# Adding lagged terms into functions [in MATLAB]

Tags: matlab

I am using a MATLAB toolbox, specifically, https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32882-armax-garch-k-sk-toolbox-estimation-forecasting-simulation-and-value-at-risk-applications

to insert data into the functions, the author defines a data matrix and then uses data(:,3) for the third column which represents a series.

I would like to do this put add data(:,3) lagged by one period.

My question: is there a way I can write something in Matlab that lags the dataset by one period which can be inserted into the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to lag a series by one time period, with the time period being however you collect the data, for example, daily data, lag the series by one day.

If so you can use the `lagmatrix`

To provide an example,

```
LAGGEDX = lagmatrix(data(:,3),1)
```

This would lag your `data(:,3)` series by one day if it is daily data, you could then insert LAGGEDX in replace of `data(:,3)`.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly, could I lag it by more than one period?

Comment: Yes, just change the 1 to any number, if you chose 10 it will lag it by 10 periods etc.